# Generate Combo Box list from column entries, without duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing car manufacturer list in Excel.

I populate a Combo Box from column D2.

- United States
- United States
- Japan
- Germany
- France

United States has many car companies, but I want to show United States only once in my Combo Box.

Is there a way to modify Excel or write VBA so that each country is shown in Combo Box only once.

[image: Car manufacturers in Excel]

Comment: Column D2?  Starting from Cell D2?

Comment: Yes, starting from cell D2. Sorry for my bad English language. I am rookie in Excel.

Comment: Is this an activex or a form control?

Comment: It is ActiveX control

Answer (score 0):

Code would go in a [standard module](http://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html) which can be added via the VBE (<kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>F11</kbd>)

**Option 1 using a dictionary to collect unique countries**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PopulateCombo()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'change as appropriate

    Dim lastRowInD As Long
    Dim dedupRange As Range

    lastRowInD = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Set dedupRange = ws.Range("D2:D" & lastRowInD)

    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim currCell As Range

    For Each currCell In dedupRange
         If Not dict.Exists(currCell.Value2) Then dict.Add currCell.Value2, currCell.Value2
    Next currCell

    Dim key As Variant

    With ws.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object
        .Clear
        For Each key In dict.Keys
            .AddItem dict(key)
        Next key

    End With

End Sub
```

**Option 2: Using de-duplicate Excel functionality.**

Warning: This deletes duplicates from the sheet in column D.

This works if you have an ActiveX comboxbox in a sheet and a named range called `Countries` which is created by  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>F3</kbd> to open the `Name Manager` and then entering

Name: Countries

Refers to:   `=OFFSET(Sheet2!$D$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$1048576),1)`

Adjust  $D$1048576 if you have an earlier version of Excel with a smaller row limit of 65536.

```
Public Sub PopulateCombo()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'change as appropriate

    Dim lastRowInD As Long
    Dim dedupRange As Range

    lastRowInD = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Set dedupRange = ws.Range("D2:D" & lastRowInD)

    dedupRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    With ws.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object
       .List = ws.Range("Countries").Value
    End With

End Sub
```